# Swift Darwin notifications and background fetch

Tags: swift, swift3, notifications, darwin, background-fetch

I have an app which is set up to use background fetch, remote notifications and push notifications (and app groups).

I have the app working so that on receipt of a push notification, it will wake up from the background and perform some code.

I am wondering if I send a Darwin notification from one app to another (they are both contained in an app group) then will the app come to life if it has been suspended by the OS like it does with remote notifications. I can't find any info on this.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Augie No sorry. I don't think this functionality is possible